# generating MD5 idHash directly in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, select, insert, md5

In my table I have an userID that is auto-incremented. In the same row I have an idHash. Is it possible to generate the idHash (simply an MD5 sum) from it directly with the same INSERT statement so that I don't have to SELECT the id, and then UPDATE the idHash again?

Problem is: I do not know the userID before it is being generated (auto-incremented) by MySQL.

Thanks
Frank

PS: I'm using PHP.
PPS: This question is all about a SINGLE INSERT. I know that I can use PHP or other languages to manually select the data and then update it.

Comment: You want to make a hash of an int?.. Why?

Comment: Yes. Should I better not do that?

Comment: Because I use it with PHP/HTML in forms etc.

Comment: The problem with using a hash of your ID in another column is that you could change one and not the other. If you don't want to use an int in PHP, you could use a GUID (UUID in mysql). Int is still going to be quicker than a UUID when used as an index/key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it within a single `INSERT` statement.

What  you probably *could* do is use an INSERT trigger, that both determines the new ID, hashes it, and *then* updates the record.

Answer (score 0):

PHP snippet

```
<?
$tablename      = "tablename";
$next_increment     = 0;
$qShowStatus        = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '$tablename'";
$qShowStatusResult  = mysql_query($qShowStatus) or die ( "Query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br/>" . $qShowStatus );

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qShowStatusResult);
$next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];

echo "next increment number: [$next_increment]";
?>
```

This will get you the next auto-increment and then you can use this in your insert.

Note: This is not perfect (Your method is imperfect as you will effectively have 2 primary keys)

From: http://blog.jamiedoris.com/geek/560/

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can recommend is using the last insert ID instead of re-querying the table. Here is a simplified example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (....)";
$mysqli->query($query);

$newUserID = $mysqli->insert_id;

$query = "UPDATE users SET idHash = MD5(userID) WHERE userID = $newUserID";
$mysqli->query($query);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no "secure" way for doing this in the same query if you're using `auto_increment`.

However, if rows are never deleted in your table, you can use this little trick :

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3, idhash) 
values ('', '', '', md5(select max(id) from mytable))
```

I don't understand why you need to hash the `id` though, why not use the `id` directly ?

Comment: Thanks, Krtek. I am actually using the id directly for most things on the server side. However, in my forms in HTML (client side = visible to users) I use the hash so that a hacker can not simply increment the ID by one and then access/manipulate other users data.

Comment: I then basically have a PHP function that converts the idHash to the actual userID and then I keep on using the userID.

Comment: @Frank if the hacker knows you hash your ids with md5, which isn't hard to determine, it can access the data as easily, I don't think this is a good way to secure your system.

Comment: @Krtek +1 - security by obscurity is not the answer

Comment: Thanks JD. Good to know. I thought it was reasonably save, but you convinced me that I should reconsider the current design.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, idHash TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl (idHash) VALUES (MD5(LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1));
SELECT *, MD5(id) FROM tbl;
```

Note this will only work on single-row inserts as `LAST_INSERT_ID` returns the insert ID of the first row inserted.

Performing `MD5(column_name)` on an auto_increment value does not work as the value has not been generated yet, so it is essentially calling `MD5(0)`.

Comment: This won't work, `last_insert_id()` returns the last inserted id for any insertion, whatever the table, so if you insert in another table before this query, the value won't be the right one.

Comment: Mm I was expecting some sort of concurrency issue - I think a trigger or another update would be the way to go then.